# Can I install Mint but defer setting language, timezone, username/password, etc.?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, system-installation

Going the follow-your-nose route, I can take a Mint install medium, set up the language, timezone, username, password, etc. during the install process, and at the end when I'm done setting all these factors, and not before, I can remove the installation medium.

Is there a straightforward way I can alter this workflow so that I completely install the system and then later have the end user specify all these details without needing the install medium?

Answer (score 0):

One note: I got the impression, but have not tested, that Linux Mint OEM, which is available in 64 bit but not 32 bit, allows complete installation with the details I mentioned being filled on after a computer ships.

The 64-bit OEM version of Mint is at http://www.linuxmint.com/release.php?id=21.

Answer (score -2):

I just install linux-mint in Wmware;creating a username and password is require during the installation, I dont think you can skip it, and you also need "install medium" or CD during the installation process.

Comment: One point of clarification: my question is not about what the usual process entails; it is about what, if anything, can be done to support something that is not obviously available from the usual install process. In other words, I wasn't asking, "Does the usual install process support ______?", but more of "Is there an alternative to the usual install process that allows _______ which the usual process does not obviously provide?"